# PHP json_encode wrap content into [ ]

Tags: php, jquery, json

in PHP I get result this way:

```
$result = $prepared->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

then I send it into file as json data:

```
$file = 'result.json';
file_put_contents($file, json_encode($result));
```

but problem is, that the content in result.json is wrapped into **[ ]** and this is problem when I use jQuery $getJSON method....when I have tried manually delete the **[ ]**,  then $getJSON work fine

Comment: It is wrapped in `[]` because `fetchAll()` always returns a 2D array. How many rows do you expect to get back? If exactly one, you can use `fetch()` instead, but if you get multiple rows, they _must_ be returned as an array.

Comment: When you say "wrapped into [ ]", can you give an example of the output you get, and the output you expect?

Comment: With: `json_encode($array, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)` you can encode it into an object.

Comment: jQuery's $.getJSON method is perfectly capable of handling arrays in JSON. You just need to process it correctly.

Comment: `json_encode($result[0])` magically unwraps your json

Comment: yes, yes ..this is exactly what I need json_encode($result[0])...super and Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Very simple. Just use JSON_FORCE_OBJECT when you are encoding to remove the **[ ]** wrappings:

```
file_put_contents($file, json_encode($result, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT));
```

Also, ceejayoz is correct, `$.getJSON` can handle arrays if you process it properly.

Also, vp_arth is correct that `json_encode($result[0])` will solve your problem.

Comment: thank You...works fine and also I would like to know the way how to process $.getJSON in a case when is array wrapped in [ ], so I have to look for something. If You know and will be so kind to explain it will be perfect

Comment: now I see when I use json_encode($result, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT) the json output is in strucure {"0":{"id":"24","uniq":"20141118-2309-FHDC",...}}..what means the "0" ...? thank You

Comment: The "0" is the index of the array. If I helped you out, give me a check ;).